# Apache2 Redirect https to http with no certificate

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I have read all the posts here regarding this, however none have worked.

My attempt has been to edit the 000-default and redirect port 443 to 80 with no success.

Any ideas thinking out the box would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in your /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName yourname.site.com
        ProxyPass         / http://127.0.0.1:80/
        ProxyPassReverse  / http://127.0.0.1:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to load your file
    a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Comment: Do i have to install a proxy software?